# Assign decile for each row according to group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 10,000 observations and would like to have a new column with the corresponding decile for each row. The decile distribution should be grouped by year. What would be the best way to do so?

```
   year       value quartile
1  2000  2.55118169       NA
2  2000  0.79755259       NA
3  2000  0.16918905       NA
4  2001  1.73359245       NA
5  2001  0.41027113       NA
6  2001  0.73012966       NA
7  2002 -1.35901658       NA
8  2002 -0.80591167       NA
9  2002  0.48966739       NA
10 2003  0.88856758       NA
11 2003  0.05146856       NA
12 2003 -0.12310229       NA
```

Comment: Decile, or quartile as in your example data?

Comment: By decile, my dataset has hundreds of values for each year, only included a sample above

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using `dplyr` may get what you want. Assuming there are >= 10 values per year in the actual `mydata`.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(decile = ntile(value, 10)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Tried this but it does not seem to give me equal sized deciles across the years. Eg, I have 500 observations for Year 2017, but decile 1 has 100 observations while decile 10 has 50 observations

Comment: I get 50 observations per decile per group when I run: `tibble(year = c(rep(2016, 500), rep(2017, 500)), value = sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(decile = ntile(value, 10)) %>% count(decile)`. So perhaps something else is going on with your data.

Comment: @Alex do you have ties?

Answer (score 0):

The `ave` function gives you a the result of evaluating a function by grouping factors (in this case years). the `dplyr::ntile` function is useful here for getting the deciles.

```
mydata$decile <- ave(mydata$value, mydata$year, FUN=function(x) { dplyr::ntile(x, 10) } )
```